# Simulate Minix Neo X5 ROM with Android Virtual Device (AVD)

Tags: android, android-emulator, kernel, android-hardware

I had tried to simulate Minix Neo X5 ROM by following these guides "[test android rom into sdk emulator before installing to your phone](http://paperknots.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/test-android-rom-into-sdk-emulator-before-installing-to-your-phone/)" and
"[how to use android emulator to test](http://viral-cs.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-use-android-emulator-to-test.html)". 
Adding to the guides: I had downloaded the [Minix Neo X5 Android 4.2.2 rom](http://minixforums.com/threads/neo-x5-4-2-2-firmware-006-6th-march-2014.4435/) and extracted it to the location `C:\Users\<user>\.android\avd\minix.avd`. Then renamed the image to system.img.

I had searched on google without being able to find detailed information. However the emulator shows only a black screen, and it seems that there is a kernel panic. The question is therefore what might be wrong, hardware configuration, software or images?

**UPDATE**
I forgot to tell that I am using a Windows machine.

**Minix Neo X5 products overview:** http://www.minix.com.hk/Products/MINIX-NEOX5.html

**config.ini:** http://pastebin.com/jcQAZC4t

**hardware-qemu.ini:** http://pastebin.com/znn3fnnC

**Kernel & debug (all):** http://pastebin.com/6BeSZsqy

(Line 223 to 224)

```
emulator: System partition format: yaffs2
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x40000000,initfile=C:\Users\Henrik\.android\avd\minix.avd/system.img
```

(Line 412 to 447)

```
init: cannot open '/initlogo.rle'
yaffs: dev is 32505856 name is "mtdblock0"
yaffs: passed flags ""
yaffs: Attempting MTD mount on 31.0, "mtdblock0"
yaffs: dev is 32505857 name is "mtdblock1"
yaffs: passed flags ""
yaffs: Attempting MTD mount on 31.1, "mtdblock1"
yaffs_read_super: isCheckpointed 0
yaffs: dev is 32505858 name is "mtdblock2"
yaffs: passed flags ""
yaffs: Attempting MTD mount on 31.2, "mtdblock2"
yaffs_read_super: isCheckpointed 0
init: cannot find '/system/bin/servicemanager', disabling 'servicemanager'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/vold', disabling 'vold'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/qemu-props', disabling 'qemu-props'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/netd', disabling 'netd'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/debuggerd', disabling 'debuggerd'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/rild', disabling 'ril-daemon'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/surfaceflinger', disabling 'surfaceflinger'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/app_process', disabling 'zygote'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/drmserver', disabling 'drm'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/mediaserver', disabling 'media'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/installd', disabling 'installd'
init: cannot find '/system/etc/install-recovery.sh', disabling 'flash_recovery'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/keystore', disabling 'keystore'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/qemud', disabling 'qemud'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/logcat', disabling 'goldfish-logcat'
init: cannot find '/system/etc/init.goldfish.sh', disabling 'goldfish-setup'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/sh', disabling 'console'
emulator: _qemudPipe_init: Service 'adb-debug' has not been registered!
emulator: _qemudPipe_init: Service 'adb-debug' has not been registered!
emulator: _qemudPipe_init: Service 'adb' has not been registered!
emulator: _qemudPipe_init: Service 'adb-debug' has not been registered!
emulator: _qemudPipe_init: Service 'adb-debug' has not been registered!
emulator: _qemudPipe_init: Service 'adb-debug' has not been registered!
emulator: _qemudPipe_init: Service 'adb-debug' has not been registered!
```